# replace results with data in database

Tags: php, database

I'm pretty new with php but getting the hang of it.

I've got a tool that gives back results

the results that i get back is can be different each time but shows for example:
101, 102, 103, 104

These results are set in `$errorcodes`

These numbers refer to a number in database what i have. 
these numbers are in column 1, and what the number means is in column 2
like:

```
column1:              column 2:
101                    error 1
102                    error 2
103                    error 3
```

How can a replace the result numbers with the value's in column 2 is my question.

I hope anyone understand what i mean and can help me.

Comment: `select column2 where column1 = 101`